# Allowing remote connection to MySQL through traefik and domain with port 3306

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, traefik

I have the following docker compose which has `traefik`,`mysql` and a `domain` added to it.

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql1:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mysql-network
    volumes:
      - mysql-instance1-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mysql1.rule=Host(`shared1.example.com`)
      - traefik.tcp.routers.mysql1.entryPoints=mysql
    mem_limit: 512m
    cpus: 0.5

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mysql-network
    command:
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--api.dashboard=false"
      - "--api.debug=false"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--log.LEVEL=DEBUG"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=example@example.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      - "--accesslog.filepath=/logs/access.log"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https"
      - "--providers.docker.network=mysql-network"
      - "--entrypoints.mysql.address=:3306"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  mysql-instance1-data:

networks:
  mysql-network:
    external: true
```

With this, I need to access mysql from WorkBench using the host shared1.example.com and port 3306.  had tried the above one and its starts without any error and listens to the 3306 port but still doesnt allows workbench to connect.

Any Ideas or Thoughts on this?